# wrong values being pushed into a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON string containing 4 objects, and each contains an Array `tennisballs` where `this.tennisballs.length` is about `2000`. In my code, I thought I should get an array of 4 averages of all tennisballs' weights, but apparently I get an array of 2000 in length. Why is that?

```
$.each(data, function () {
    var average = Array();
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tennisballs.length; ++i) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.tennisballs[i][2]);
        if (i == (this.tennisballs.length - 1)) {
            average[i] = sum / this.tennisballs.length;
            average.push(average[i]);
            console.log("sum: " + sum + ", average[" + i + "]" + average[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log("average array:" + average);
});
```

Comment: To make your code cleaner and more efficient, you may want to consider just summing in the `for` loop, and then performing the division and appending to the _Array_ immediately **after** the loop. Furthermore, you might find `console.log` more helpful if you pass multiple arguments instead of relying on an implicit cast to string, i.e. `console.log("average array", average);`. Finally, using `Array()` is not the preferred way to create an _Array_ (unless you want a specific constructor features), use an _Array literal_ `[]`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. WRT `array()`, you are saying instead of using average = [] makes the code more efficient? That's really interesting, I will have to read more about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign an item at a specific index of an array and that index is outside of the length of the array, the length is adjusted after that index.

When you assign the average to `average[i]` and `i` is around 2000, it will make the array have a length of around 2000 although most items in the array are undefined.

To just put the average last in the array, don't assign it at index `i`, just push it. Use `average.length-1` to get the index of the last item in the array. Also, you should create the array outside the loop, and display it after the loop:

```
var average = Array();
$.each(data, function() {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < this.tennisballs.length; ++i){
    sum += parseFloat(this.tennisballs[i][2]);
    if(i == (this.tennisballs.length - 1) ) {
      average.push(sum / this.tennisballs.length);
      console.log("sum: " + sum + ", average["+(average.length-1)+"]: " + average[average.length-1]); 
    }
  }
});
console.log("average array:" + average);
```

---

Side note: You can just push the avarage after the loop, instead of checking the index for each iteration in the loop:

```
var average = Array();
$.each(data, function() {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < this.tennisballs.length; ++i){
    sum += parseFloat(this.tennisballs[i][2]);
  }
  average.push(sum / this.tennisballs.length);
  console.log("sum: " + sum + ", average["+(average.length-1)+"]: " + average[average.length-1]); 
});
console.log("average array:" + average);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing an item in the 2000th position of the `average` Array so it's length would always be 2000.

E.g:

```
> a = Array()
[]
> a[2000 - 1] = 2000/10
200
> a.length
2000
```

The remaining items in the `Array` `average` would be `undefined` in exception of the last item